# MPMoviePlayerNotification Playback Progress Notification?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a Notification for reaching a certain point in a MPMoviePlayerController?

Something akin to MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification but for progress between 0.0 and 1.0 instead of 1.0 (end of the video)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing within the MediaPlayer framework.

You will need to instantiate a timer that periodically checks the current playback position.